# AngularJS - Parse error looping through hex values with ng-style

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've tried the following approaches in my ng-repeat:

```
 <a data-ng-repeat="style in webStyles" data-ng-style="background-color: \'{{style.bgColor}}\'">{{style.name}}</a>
 <a data-ng-repeat="style in webStyles" data-ng-style="background-color: '{{style.bgColor}}'">{{style.name}}</a>
 <a data-ng-repeat="style in webStyles" data-ng-style="background-color: {{style.bgColor}}">{{style.name}}</a>
 <a data-ng-repeat="style in webStyles" data-ng-style="background-color: style.bgColor">{{style.name}}</a>
```

These are the values:

```
        { name: "Default", bgColor: "#4E463F"},
        { name: "Style1",  bgColor: "#3A4558"},
        { name: "Style1",  bgColor: "#fff"},
        { name: "Style3",  bgColor: "#f78c40"}
```

But am recv'ng a parse error pertaining to the hex (#) symbol.

What is the correct approach in passing hex value for ng-style in an ng-repeat?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-style takes an object, try this

```
<a data-ng-repeat="style in webStyles" data-ng-style="{'background-color': style.bgColor}">{{style.name}}</a>
```